# Shutting down of Raspberry pi

Tags: microcontroller

hello there guys I have this raspberry pi and I got confuse when shutting down the pi
is use the following code:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

but the problem is that the pi still has this red LED on I'm confuse if it's ok to unplug the pi? will it damage the SDCARD? or the Pi?

is there any way to completely shutdown the pi inlcuding the power?

Comment: Which RPi do you have?

Comment: i am using an RPI 3 B+

Comment: check out http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/, I bet your question is answered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red LED being on after shutdown is normal.
When you shut down the green LED will start blinking very fast, which means it is writing to SD card. When the screen has disappeared and it is safe you will see a fast regular blinking pattern on the green LED: ten times on/off and then all the LEDs but the red one will go out. Then it is safe to remove the power.

No, the Pi does NOT turn off its power like .e.g. a PC.

By the way:

- The Raspberry-Pi stack exchange is the better place to ask this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42929/how-to-safely-switch-off-the-raspberry-pi/42945
- Since a few years it is a lot more difficult to mess up the SD-card. Not impossible but a lot more then it was in the begin period.
- All this you can find on the internet in many places.

Comment: thanks sir/mam great help I am just worried maybe I done wrong with the shutting down of Rpi thanks appreciated

Answer (score 1):

On known schematics for Rpi the RED LED is connected to 3.3 V power rail, either directly, or enabled by "power_good" voltage monitor (on RPi3).

[image: Raspberry-pi3 model B]

As long as +5V is applied over USB u-B receptacle, the on-board regulators will produce "valid 3.3V", and the RED LED will be on. This is independent on any state of MCU, and will be always on. Shutting down the MCU properly should result in no damage to uSD. Once the GREEN "activity" LED stops blinking, it is safe to unplug the board.